# Simple interactive prompt in C++

Tags: c++

I work on an application that usually runs unattended. Now I need to add to it something like an interactive prompt. In the interactive mode the operator will be able to give simple commands to the application - nothing fancy, simple commands like *start* and *stop*. Parametrized commands (e.g. *repeat 10*) and commands history could be nice too.

Do you know, by chance, any library that helps with such tasks. I've been thinking about something that works like `boost::program_options` or `gflags` but for an interactive prompt and not for command line parameters. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Readline is one the best known libraries for this

http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html

It is covered by GPL, so it is only possible to use in GPL-compatible programs.

I did a quick search for alternatives, and found this:

http://github.com/antirez/linenoise

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping there is something that allows me actually to define the commands so the library will handle all the parsing.

Comment: @Lou Franco: +1 for letting me discover linenoise, a small gem! :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if the following is a reasonable amount of work for what you're trying to do, but Python has a very nice Command Line Interface (CLI) building library called cmd2. If it's possible to expose the relevant parts of your apps to Python using [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) or [CTypes](http://www.python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/), then doing the rest should be easy.

Here's a nice video presentation about cmd2:

[PyCon 2010:Easy command-line applications with cmd and cmd2](http://pycon.blip.tv/file/3261338/)

HTH

Comment: This is an over-kill in my case, but it's nice to be aware of the option. Maybe I'll do it just because it's an interesting experiment :)

Comment: Sorry it wasn't of much use to you, but yes, it is a an interesting experiment that can turn very addictive :) Good luck with your search.

Answer (score 1):

One possibilty is to open a TCP port and accept messages in text format. Then you can telnet to that port and issue simple commands.

Comment: I see I misunderstood the question. I didn't read carefully and thought he wanted to add an interactive prompt to an already running application. If more think my answer is totally irrelevant I will delete it.

Comment: indeed it isn't exactly what I had in mind, but I like the trick. If I understand correctly, this way I don't need GNU Readline - the telnet client will supply most of the readline functionality and I will just need to parse the resulting string. Am I correct?

Comment: GNU readline is completely orthogonal to telnet and to parsing. It provides an editable command line prompt including a history. Telnet provides a way to open and use a TCP connection to transfer text to and from your application. There might be telnet clients which provide or use readline functionality themselves.